# Pandas - Create column using itertuples

Tags: python, list, loops, pandas, python-itertools

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with `AcctId`, `Latitude` and `Longitude`. I also have a list of coordinates. I am trying to calculate the distance between the Latitude and Longitude and each coordinate pair in the list (using the haversine formula). Then I want to return the minimum distance, and create a new column in the dataframe with the value.

However, my output table is only returning the distance value for the last row in the loop. I've tried using `itertuples`, `iterrows`, and a normal loop, but none of the methods are quite working for me.

```
df
AcctId   Latitude   Longitude
123      40.50      -90.13
123      40.53      -90.21
123      40.56      -90.45
123      40.63      -91.34

coords = [41.45,-95.13,39.53,-100.42,45.53,-95.32]

for row in df.itertuples():
    Latitude = row[1]
    Longitude = row[2]
    distances = []
    lat = []
    lng = []
    for i in xrange(0, len(coords),2):
          distances.append(haversine_formula(Latitude,coords[i],Longitude,coords[i+1])
          lat.append(coords[i])
          lng.append(coords[i+1])
          min_distance = min(distances)
    df['Output'] = min_distance
```

**Desired Output:**

```
df
AcctId   Latitude    Longitude    Output
123      40.50      -90.13         23.21
123      40.53      -90.21         38.42
123      40.56      -90.45         41.49
123      40.63      -91.34         42.45
```

**Actual Output:**

```
df
AcctId   Latitude    Longitude    Output
123      40.50      -90.13         42.45
123      40.53      -90.21         42.45
123      40.56      -90.45         42.45
123      40.63      -91.34         42.45
```

**Final Code**

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    def min_distance(row):
        here = (row.Latitude, row.Longitude)
        return min(haversine(here, coord) for coord in coords)
    df['Nearest_Distance'] = df.apply(min_distance, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`pandas.DataFrame.apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).  Something like:

#### Code:

```
df['output'] = df.apply(min_distance, axis=1)
```

#### Test Code:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u'''
        AcctId   Latitude   Longitude
        123      40.50      -90.13
        123      40.53      -90.21
        123      40.56      -90.45
        123      40.63      -91.34'''), header=1)

coords = [
    (41.45, -95.13),
    (39.53, -100.42),
    (45.53, -95.32)
]

from haversine import haversine

def min_distance(row):
    here = (row.Latitude, row.Longitude)
    return min(haversine(here, coord) for coord in coords)

df['output'] = df.apply(min_distance, axis=1)

print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
   AcctId  Latitude  Longitude      output
0     123     40.50     -90.13  432.775598
1     123     40.53     -90.21  425.363959
2     123     40.56     -90.45  404.934516
3     123     40.63     -91.34  330.649766
```

Comment: That was amazing. I've been working on this far too long. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This solution works, but when applying to a large dataframe (>2MM rows), `df.apply` runs very slowly. Any recommendations for an alternative to `df.apply`?

Comment: I would bet the the primary lack of speed is in the haversine calculation. You should profile the code.  And if I am right you might look at doing an estimate of the distance to only need to do the haversine on  a subset of the points.

Comment: What would be a good method for estimating the distance? Forgive my ignorance--I'm fairly new to Python.

Comment: Well if you are below a certain latitude you can simply do `sqrt(d_lat**2 + d_long**2)` for a first approximation that can allow you to find things close by.  And maybe even simpler just `min(d_lat, d_long)` to finds close by candidates.  Will really depend on the nature of your data.